# Jquery regex cutting <script> tags

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I want to remove

```
<script (.*)>
```

and

```
 </script>
```

tags from string input.

Example:

```
var string = "<script>$('#book').load(function() { $console.log('test'); }); </script>";
```

What I would like to receive:

```
$('#book').load(function() { $console.log('test'); });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us your regex

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%5b%5e%3e%5d%2b%3e&i=%3cscript%3e%24(%27%23book%27).load(function()+%7b+%24console.log(%27test%27)%3b+%7d)%3b+%3c%2fscript%3e

Comment: `<script (.*)>` requires a space after `script`, and your input has no space after `script`. Remove the space in the regex, and your regex will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match and replace with empty string:

```
<script[^>]*>|<\/script>
```

See [RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mR4fT3/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var string = "<script>$('#book').load(function() { $console.log('test'); }); </script>";
var res = str.replace("<script>", "");
var res = str.replace("</script>", "");
```

It's not recommended to use regular expressions on DOM.

Comment: "It's not recommended to use regular expressions on DOM." - That's not necessarily true.  It is not recommended to "parse" HTML using regex, but that is not what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script[^>]*>|<\/script>
```

It works perfect for me. I mean solution:

```
test.replace(/<script[^>]*>|<\/script>/g, '');
```

works fine. Thank you Karthik Manchala

Comment: You should accept Karithik's answer, and add this as an edit to the bottom of your question